# How to iterate through object keys / obtain keys of object

Tags: botframework, bot-framework-composer

I am trying to create a dialog that displays a object in a dynamic manner in an adaptive card. Dynamic as in I don't know what the object keys are, how many keys there are, etc.
Assuming that the object will not have nested arrays or other objects (basically the object will look like a map), how can I extract all the keys and put them in an array?

An example of an object that I wish to extract the keys from :

```
{
    "symbol": "MSFT",
    "companyName": "Microsoft Corporation",
    "primaryExchange": "Nasdaq Global Select",
    "sector": "Technology",
    "calculationPrice": "close",
    "open": 127.42,
    "openTime": 1556890200,
    "close": 128.9,
    "closeTime": 1556913600,
    "high": 129.43,
    "low": 127.25,
    "latestPrice": 128.9,
    "latestSource": "Close",
    "latestTime": "May 3, 2019",
    "latestUpdate": 1556913600,
    "latestVolume": 24835154,
    "iexRealtimePrice": null,
    "iexRealtimeSize": null,
    "iexLastUpdated": null,
    "delayedPrice": 128.9,
    "delayedPriceTime": 1556913600,
    "extendedPrice": 129.04,
    "extendedChange": 0.14,
    "extendedChangePercent": 0.00109,
    "extendedPriceTime": 1556917190,
    "previousClose": 126.21,
    "change": 2.69,
    "changePercent": 0.02131,
    "iexMarketPercent": null,
    "iexVolume": null,
    "avgTotalVolume": 22183270,
    "iexBidPrice": null,
    "iexBidSize": null,
    "iexAskPrice": null,
    "iexAskSize": null,
    "marketCap": 987737229888,
    "peRatio": 30.84,
    "week52High": 131.37,
    "week52Low": 93.96,
    "ytdChange": 0.30147812013916003
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [select prebuilt function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/adaptive-expressions/adaptive-expressions-prebuilt-functions?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#select) from Adaptive Expressions.

It would be something like:
`select(myobject, x, x.key)` and assigning that to a new property (or however you need to use that array).

You can test this out further by using the expressions playground:
https://playgroundclient.azurewebsites.net/

I ran a quick test with the expression:

```
select(myobject, x, x.key)
```

And my data/properties as:

```
{
  "myobject": {
    "symbol": "MSFT",
    "companyName": "Microsoft Corporation",
    "primaryExchange": "Nasdaq Global Select",
    "sector": "Technology",
    "calculationPrice": "close"
  }
}
```

And I get the result:

```
["symbol","companyName","primaryExchange","sector","calculationPrice"]
```

Please let me know if I misunderstood your requirement/question. And if this answers your question; please mark as answered.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done use **Keys** method.

```js
const myObject = {
    "symbol": "MSFT",
    "companyName": "Microsoft Corporation",
    "primaryExchange": "Nasdaq Global Select",
    "sector": "Technology",
}

const keys = Object.keys(myObject);

keys.map(key=>console.log(key,"->", myObject[key]));
```

Now if you have inner object you need to make a function that will check is it object or not. If it's object then you can run the **keys** method again and push it to a new array.